# omit nested properties with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to get rid of the properties `5MinuteRate` and `15MinuteRate`in the following object.

```
var object = { requestsPerSecond:
   { mean: 1710.2180279856818,
     count: 10511,
     'currentRate': 1941.4893498239829,
     '1MinuteRate': 168.08263156623656,
     '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
     '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095 } };
```

Lodash's omit()-function doesn't seem to work on nested objects. The following code doesn't work:

```
console.log(_.omit(object, 'requestsPerSecond.count'));
```

EDIT:

I tried this but it doesn't work quite right:

```
var subObject = _.omit(object.requestsPerSecond, '5MinuteRate', '15MinuteRate');

console.log(_.merge(object, subObject));
```

Comment: you can merge it with an empty shell with function values if you just need json, otherwise a custom map() callback and a couple `delete` statements are the simplest bet.

Comment: I tried the merge but I made a mistake. the nested Object is merged at the top-level. Could you take a look at it (in the question)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were almost there. Just assign what would be the result of your `subObject` to `object.requestsPerSecond`.

```js
var object = {
  requestsPerSecond: {
    mean: 1710.2180279856818,
    count: 10511,
    'currentRate': 1941.4893498239829,
    '1MinuteRate': 168.08263156623656,
    '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
    '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095
  }
};

object.requestsPerSecond = _.omit(object.requestsPerSecond, '5MinuteRate', '15MinuteRate');

console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _.omit  will return object.requestsPerSecond or object  in that case ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI `_.omit` returns the `requestsPerSecond` sub-object, minus the specified properties. Notice how I'm setting it back to `object.requestsPerSecond` to overwrite that previous value.

Answer (score 7):

Use unset: https://lodash.com/docs#unset , it gets cleaner:

```
var obj = { 
  requestsPerSecond: { 
    mean: 1710.2180279856818,
    count: 10511,
    'currentRate': 1941.4893498239829,
    '1MinuteRate': 168.08263156623656,
    '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
    '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095 
  } 
};

_.forEach(['requestsPerSecond.5MinuteRate', 'requestsPerSecond.15MinuteRate'], 
  function(omitProperty) {
    obj = _.unset(obj, omitProperty);
  }
);

// Or avoiding the "extra" loop.
obj = _.unset(obj, 'requestsPerSecond.5MinuteRate');
obj = _.unset(obj, 'requestsPerSecond.15MinuteRate');
```

Comment: Thanks @OscarRyz , I've edit the answer to use `_.unset` ; I think originally I thought about it, but typed it wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Lodash **_.omit** works with nested objects. It appears that they improved the function since your question :)

```
object = _.omit(object, 'requestsPerSecond.5MinuteRate', 'requestsPerSecond.15MinuteRate');
```

**UPDATE**

*omit* will be removed from Lodash 5 onward

Comment: Looks like there will be [no `omit` in Lodash v5](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/723#issuecomment-332321054)

Comment: Does this really work? using v `4.5.0` `omit({ data: {a: 1, b: 2} }, 'data.a') == { data: { a: 1, b: 2 } }`

Comment: This does NOT work for nested properties!
Use lodash's `_.unset()` method instead!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-unset-method/

Comment: doesn't seem to be available in `omitBy`

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to omit some kind of paths deeply, here is an [omitDeep](https://deepdash.io/#omitdeep) from Deepdash:

```
obj = _.omitDeep(obj, /\.*5MinuteRate"\]$/);
```

note that this method will exclude all the matching paths at any depths.
It supports a single path or array, represented as a constant value(s) or as a regex(es).

In the case of a string path given as an argument, each path in the object will be checked to end with given criteria.
here is a more detailed [codepen for your case](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/bZvrOy)

*(Answer updated to fit most recent Deepdash v3.1.0)*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but it wanted to omit all the named properties in a nested object.

Here's a generic function that would have worked for you also.

Just use it like this `omit(object, ['name_1','name_2, ... ])`

#### Function

```js
// Variation on omit to recurse through objects and arrays
function omit(obj, arr) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (arr.includes(key)) {
        delete obj[key];
      } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
          omit(obj[key][i], arr);
        }
      } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        omit(obj[key], arr);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

var object = {
    requestsPerSecond: {
        mean: 1710.2180279856818,
        count: 10511,
        'currentRate': 1941.4893498239829,
        '1MinuteRate': 168.08263156623656,
        '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
        '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095
    }
};

object = omit(object, ['5MinuteRate','15MinuteRate']);
console.log(object);
```

and you should get a result like this

```
{
 "requestsPerSecond":
  {
    "mean": 1710.2180279856818,
    "count": 10511,
    "currentRate": 1941.4893498239828,
    "1MinuteRate": 168.08263156623656
  }
}
```

I would have liked to have used a later library I'm running test-cases inside Postman, so I'm limited in packages and versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to trying another library, partial.lenses has great support for all kind of operations on collections, including complex modifications like all the children of an object and so on.

So in your case it would be as simple as (L is just a shorthand for the import from partial.lesnes)

```
const newObject = L.remove(['requestsPerSecond','5MinuteRate'],object)
```

Now imagine that you have a different structure, where you have a set of nested properties with different names, but all with the same structure, and you want to target all of them. Imagine this example:

```
obj = { 
  requestsPerSecond: {
  first: {
    mean: 1710.2180279856818,
    count: 10511,
    '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
    '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095 
  }}
  second: {
    mean: 1710.2180279856818,
    count: 10511,
    '5MinuteRate': 34.74630977619571,
    '15MinuteRate': 11.646507524106095 
  }} 
};
```

In that case, it will be as simple as:

```
const newObject = L.remove(['requestsPerSecond',L.children,'5MinuteRate'],object)
```

Where L.children means to target all children of requestPerSecond.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me trying to do this for omitBy which is not supporting nested filtering yet, you can use this following code

```
const inputObject = {
  operation: "category",
  params: {
    city: undefined,
    location: {
      latitude: undefined,
      value: "not undefined"

    },
  },
  id: "test_id___20200101000000000",
  crawler: "crawler_id",
  queue: "task_queue",
  job: "crawler_id_scheduler_platform",
  seedId: "test_id",
};

function removeUndefined(obj) {
  return _.omitBy(obj, _.isUndefined);
}

function deepRemoveUndefined(obj) {
  if (_.isObject(obj)) {
    return removeUndefined(
      _.mapValues(obj, (val) => (val && _.isObject(val) ? deepRemoveUndefined(val) : val))
    );
  }
  return obj;
}

const cleanedObject = deepRemoveUndefined(inputObject);

console.log(cleanedObject);
```