# Is there any way to remove properties from nested objects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am having one object similar to below,

```
let obj = {
   "mode1":{
      "pool_1":[
         { "id":115 },
      ],
      "pool_2":[
         { "id":116 }
      ],
      "pool_4":[
         { "id":117 }
      ],
   },
   "mode2":{
      "pool_6":[
         { "id":122 }
      ]
   },
   "mode3":{
      "pool_1":[
         { "id":123 }
      ]
   },
   "AWS":{
      "cloud":[]
   },
   "Azure":{
      "cloud":[]
   }
}

let value_array = ["pool_1"];
```

Here,

**Step 1** : I need to remove the property from the obj which matches the value_array. For example, in the above code,  `pool_1` should get removed from `mode1' and` mode3`

**Step 2** : Need to check all the keys of the `obj` and push the empty keys into new array. For example, in the above code, `mode3` should be added into a new array like `["mode3"]`

Output should be like below,

```
["mode3"]
```

because, `mode3` is having empty object.

This is working when using the for loops. But I need to use some simple way like Lodash or Es6 methods to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Tried like below,

```
for (var key in obj) {
    for (var keys in obj[key]) {
      value_array.forEach(function (item) {
              if(keys == item){
                console.log(key)
                delete obj[key][keys]
              }
               console.log("ALL THE DETALS AFTER DELETE", obj)
          });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [omit nested properties with Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376782/omit-nested-properties-with-lodash)

Comment: Tried the same, but not got the expected answer. I need to store the empty keys in separate array

Comment: https://github.com/ironbay/dynamic/tree/master/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function, deleteRecursive or something like that, traverse the object and deleted the required keys.

We'll also build up a list of empty keys.

```js
function deleteRecursive(input, keysToDelete, inputKey = "", emptyKeys = []) {
    for(let key of Object.keys(input)) {
        if (keysToDelete.includes(key)) { 
            delete input[key];
            if (Object.keys(input).length === 0) emptyKeys.push(inputKey)
        }
        if (typeof input[key] === 'object') {
            deleteRecursive(input[key], keysToDelete, key, emptyKeys)
        }
    }
    return emptyKeys;
}

let obj = { "mode1":{ "pool_1":[ { "id":115 }, ], "pool_2":[ { "id":116 } ], "pool_4":[ { "id":117 } ], }, "mode2":{ "pool_6":[ { "id":122 } ] }, "mode3":{ "pool_1":[ { "id":123 } ] }, "AWS":{ "cloud":[] }, "Azure":{ "cloud":[] } }
let value_array = ["pool_1"];

const emptyKeys = deleteRecursive(obj, value_array)
console.log("Obj after deletion:", obj);
console.log("Empty keys:", emptyKeys );
```